# How to reorganize an array of objects (with examples) Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have an array like this:

```
[
  {date: '2018-06-22', data: [{place: 'Living Room', duration: 12}, {place: 'Kitchen', duration: 11}, {place: 'Dining Room', duration: 12}]},
  {date: '2018-06-23', data: [{place: 'Living Room', duration: 10}, {place: 'Kitchen', duration: 12}]},
  {date: '2018-06-24', data: [{place: 'Living Room', duration: 10}, {place: 'Kitchen', duration: 12}]}
]
```

How can I make convert it to:

```
[{date: '2018-06-22', 'Living Room': 12, 'Kitchen', 11, 'Dining Room': 12},
{date: '2018-06-23', 'Living Room': 10, 'Kitchen', 12, 'Dining Room': 0},
{date: '2018-06-24', 'Living Room': 10, 'Kitchen', 12, 'Dining Room': 0}]
```

I cant get my head wrapped around how to use convert the value to key, then use duration as the key value..

Any help greatly appreciated

Comment: This is invalid syntax `kitchen, 11`. So is `2018-06-22`.

Comment: @SaifUrRahman sorry typo on my part

Comment: @SaifUrRahman what's wrong with 2018-06-22 string?

Comment: You need to wrap string with quotation marks.

Comment: @SaifUrRahman ok fixed

Comment: You cannot have space in `Dining room` and `living room`. Only possible if you put it in quotes.

Comment: One issue is that only the first index has a 'Dining Room' object. To make it easier to parse, every data point should also have a 'Dining Room' value set to 0. Also, remove spaces from the place names, since spaces are not allowed in object property names

Comment: You can have spaces but that needs to be wrapped with quotation marks.

Answer (score 3):

#### Objects in JavaScript

There are a couple of issues in your starting array: keys and values should be strings. You need something like:

```
const data = [{
  date: "2018-06-22",
  data: [{
    place: "Living Room",
    duration: 12
  }, {
    place: "Kitchen",
    duration: 11
  }, {
    place: "Dining Room",
    duration: 12
  }]
},
{
  ...
}];
```

*The full object can be seen in the demo below.*

---

#### Mapping your array

You only need to modify the structure of your array of objects.

You can create a new array out of your array using the [`.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method.

> The `.map` method creates a new array with the results of calling a provided function on every element in the calling array.

```js
const result = Object.entries(data).map(([key, value]) => {

  const obj = {
    date: value.date,
    "Living Room": 0,
    "Kitchen": 0,
    "Dining Room": 0
  }
  
  value.data.forEach(({place, duration}) => {
    obj[place] = duration;
  });
  
  return obj;
  
});

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script>
  const data = [{
      date: "2018-06-22",
      data: [{
        place: "Living Room",
        duration: 12
      }, {
        place: "Kitchen",
        duration: 11
      }, {
        place: "Dining Room",
        duration: 12
      }]
    },
    {
      date: "2018-06-23",
      data: [{
        place: "Living Room",
        duration: 10
      }, {
        place: "Kitchen",
        duration: 12
      }]
    }, {
      date: "2018-06-24",
      data: [{
        place: "Living Room",
        duration: 10
      }, {
        place: "Kitchen",
        duration: 12
      }]
    }
  ];
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! But I still need Dining room: 0 in the second array. How can i do that?

Comment: I have edited my answer: you can set 0 to the default value.

Comment: @Lalaluye Don't forget to upvote/accept my answer if you found it useful for future reference.